# jQuery syntax for parsing object into variable

Tags: jquery

I am iterating through a loop using jQuery $.each:

```
$.each(obj.DATA, function( indexInArray, value, index ) {

    var dates = value[dateIndex];
    var nums = value[scoreIndex];
```

Currently, dates is bringing back this:

[image]

I'm wondering how to manipulate this array that returns so that I can set the dates variable to return something like this:

dates = ["January","February","March] .. etc.

Answer (score 0):

So if dates, is an array of dates, then you can use the map method to get an array of month names, like this:

```js
function GetMonthName(d){
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", 
                      "June", "July", "August", "September", 
                      "October", "November", "December"];
    
    return monthNames[d.getMonth()];
}

var dates = new Array();

dates.push(new Date(Date.parse('1/1/15')));
dates.push(new Date(Date.parse('2/1/15')));
dates.push(new Date(Date.parse('3/1/15')));

var chartdata = {
    labels: dates.map(GetMonthName)
  }

console.log(chartdata);
```

However, if the dates are not in chronological order, or if you have multiple dates from the same month in the array, you might not get the result you are looking for.

Comment: no - so what I need is "January","February",etc... Right now all I have is the dates variable, which returns January, 01 2015 00:00:00 February, 01 2015 00:00:00 March, 01 2015 00:00:00 etc..

Answer (score 0):

if str = January, 01 2015 00:00:00;

then monthName = str.slice(0, str.indexOf(','));

```
var dates = []; //set empty array outside
$.each(obj.DATA, function( indexInArray, value, index ) {
     // do whatever you need to do to get the str January, 01 2015 00:00:00;
     dates[index] = str.slice(0, str.indexOf(','));
}
```

Comment: Right, but I need all the months to appear as var months =  ["January","February","March"]

Comment: if you are using this $.each(obj.DATA, function( indexInArray, value, index ) { } then you can use the **index** of the function to associate the array.  I've edited the code above to include that.

Comment: I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: str is not defined in this

Comment: That's because the commented line is where you put the existing code that gives you January, 01 2015 00:00:00; which you will assign as the str variable.